# Timestamps in Ridge Regression Scikit Learn

Tags: regression, predictive-models, scikit-learn, feature-engineering, circular-statistics

I am trying to transform data for use in regression, most likely the Ridge or Lasso technique implemented in `sklearn.linear_model`.

My training data contains time stamps , which I believe may have predictive power. The time stamps reflect the time that a user placed an order for pizza. Here is an example:

The field containing the target data / labels is `elapsed_time`, which is expressed in seconds.

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.linear_model as linear_model

delivery_data = {
    'order_time' : ['2018-09-12 21:43:08', '2018-09-13 06:33:04', '2018-09-13 09:12:18'],
    'price' : [34.54, 8.63, 21.24],
    'miles' : [6, 3, 7],
    'home_type' : ['apartment', 'house', 'apartment'],
    'elapsed_time' : [2023, 1610, 1918]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(delivery_data)
df['order_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_time'])
```

The resulting DataFrame looks like this:

```
           order_time  price  miles  home_type  elapsed_time
0 2018-09-12 21:43:08  34.54      6  apartment          2023
1 2018-09-13 06:33:04   8.63      3      house          1610
2 2018-09-13 09:12:18  21.24      7  apartment          1918
```

I am trying to predict the time to deliver pizza (elapsed_time) given timestamp, quantitative, and categorical data.

I suspect that time of day is predictive but that date is less predictive.

So far, I am considering extracting only the hour from the time stamp. In this example, `order_time` would become [21, 6, 9]. My first concern is that 23:59 has an hour of 23 and 00:01 has an hour of 0. The two values are far apart, even though the order times are two minutes apart.

Is there a better way to transform this `datetime` data?

Does it make a difference that the dataset contains other quantitative data (price, miles_from_store) and categorical data (home_type)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to round time to the nearest hour, as it's a continuous variable and rounding just discards information. If the store is only open for a certain period during the day, then you can express time as a fraction of this interval (e.g. 0=opening time, 1=closing time, 0.5=halfway through).

If the store is open 24 hours, then things are more complicated because time is a circular variable (e.g. 23:59 and 00:01 are only two minutes apart, as you mentioned). In this case, one option is to transform time into two features that properly preserve the relative distance between timepoints. Suppose $t$ is the time in hours, and can take fractional values (e.g. 21.5 corresponds to 21:30). Then, let new features $t_x$ and $t_y$ be the Cartesian coordinates after mapping time onto the unit circle:

$$t_x = \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{12} t \right), \quad
t_y = \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{12} t \right)$$

Comment: I think this solution is promising because it handles the problem of the midnight boundary. I am also glad it allows me to treat time as continuous, rather than a set of categories of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 1):

From `order_time` you could also extract a categorical variable `day of week` or binary `workday`, assuming that traffic is heavier during the workdays.

If you want to use the hour you need to transform it into categorical variable using [one hot encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python/39287161#39287161), but instead of just taking the hour, you could transform timestamp into more precise time zone by splitting every day into $n$ chunks, e.g. by taking $10$ minute intervals you get $144$ time zones for every day, like they do in this example: http://radiostud.io/beat-rush-hour-traffic-with-tensorflow-machine-learning/

On the other hand, you could create a more broader categorical variable, like `part of day`, with values e.g. `morning`, `noon`, `evening`, `night`

Comment: There are problems with making time of day a categorical variable: with too many categories, you might lose many degrees of freedom (creating a non-parsimonious model); with too few, you might lose too much precision.  Categorizing it also wipes out all information about its *circular* nature, which is the issue in question.  Often there are better solutions.

Comment: +1 for poining out that `day of week` may be more useful than I had considered. And for mentioning one-hot encoding as one option while linking to an article that handles categories by assigning an integer to each category.